# When i add product to woocommerce 4.4.1 error message come out

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

When i try to add product to wordpresss -> woocomerce, there is an error message:

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') OR p.product_id = 30582 OR g.apply_to = 'all' GROUP BY g.id ORDER BY g' at line 5]

```
SELECT 
    g.*
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_id) as `categories`
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_id) as `products` 
FROM wpav_za_groups as g 
    LEFT JOIN wpav_za_categories_to_groups as c ON c.group_id = g.id 
    LEFT JOIN wpav_za_products_to_groups as p ON p.group_id = g.id 
WHERE 
    c.category_id IN () 
    OR p.product_id = 30582 
    OR g.apply_to = 'all' 
GROUP BY g.id 
ORDER BY g.priority ASC
```

Can you help to check what is the issue about?

Comment: How to edit this code? I mean can you guide to edit this code?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing text or data in the IN clause

```
c.category_id IN ('test1','teswt2')
```

Instead of text1 and test2 you have to enter your own text or data

```
SELECT 
    g.*
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_id) as `categories`
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_id) as `products` 
FROM wpav_za_groups as g 
    LEFT JOIN wpav_za_categories_to_groups as c ON c.group_id = g.id 
    LEFT JOIN wpav_za_products_to_groups as p ON p.group_id = g.id 
WHERE 
    c.category_id IN ('test1','teswt2') 
    OR p.product_id = 30582 
    OR g.apply_to = 'all' 
GROUP BY g.id 
ORDER BY g.priority ASC
```

Comment: Not withpout knowing where you build and run thst sql query